# ChromeDriver 2.25 crash for chrome 55

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

I am working with Selenium and using Chrome browser v55.2883.75m (which is the latest).
According to this [enter link description here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) ChromeDriver 2.25 should support my Chrome version. But, sadly, it doesn't. Does anyone has an idea what can i do?

Answer (score 1):

Update to chromeDriver 2.27, it works